# How connect to monerod via xmrig

Tags: monerod, mining, xmrig

I have a node running monerod. The "problem" i've that node with password and i don't know how to connect xmrig with login.

I tried various combinations such -u -p, -O user:pass, -u user:wallet -p etc. Some combination just no connect other say invalid wallet.

Xmrig have option to connect monerod with login? i can connect without login but the question is with password.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use authentication (i.e. `monerod -rpc-login arg`) when mining directly to a daemon (e.g. `xmrig --daemon*`). Also note that the *user* field (`xmrig --user,-u`) should be your primary wallet address.